# Django table to grid formatting (data processing)

Tags: python, django, datatable

I'm prompting some data in a table format with django

with a very simple table like:

```
{% for column in myresult %}
{% endfor %}

{% for index, row in myresult.iterrows %}
{% for value in row.values %}
```

Pretty standard code found online which works very well in my newbye case.

However, now I'm dealing with this table which I would really like to format like a grid, which involves some post processing of these data.

The image example of what I have and what I would like to have is in this screenshot, much simpler than explaning it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMPYz.jpg

Basically every record represent in which column (variable 1), and in which row (variable 2) every value (variable 3) should fall.

Which is the easier way to do this? Hope the question makes sense.

EDIT as it was probably unclear. in the screenshot you can see:
Table 1 (at the top) is how I get the data.
Table 2 (at the bottom) is how I want to display them.
Question is: how to do that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about a style/method to display data, not a programming problem

Comment: Please clarify, you want to create table 2 on basis of table 1, is that right?

Comment: @markwalker_ I'm asking how to do that on the programming side, I just shown how I get the data and how I want to represent them. Sorry for being unclear maybe, but I don't know how to create the table in the bottom getting the data as from the top. Edited original text.

Comment: @AnupamChaplot exactly, table1 is how i get the data, table 2 is how I want to display them. I know how to display them easily in a table format as in table 1, but I'm interested in creating table 2.